# Is this argument valid?

Tags: operator-theory

Can someone check if the following argument is valid? Show that if $T$ is an operator and operator $T \circ  T$ has eigenvalue $\lambda^{2}$, than $\lambda$ or $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.
$\textbf{Proof.}$ Let $\overline{x}$ be eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$. From the assumtion we have that $$T^{2}\overline{x}=\lambda^{2}\overline{x},$$ so $$T^{2}\overline{x}-\lambda^{2}\overline{x}=0,$$ then $$0=(T^{2}-\lambda^{2})\overline{x}.$$ From the assumption that $\overline{x}$ is an eigenvector we have $\overline{x}\neq \overline{0}$. This implies that $(T^{2}-\lambda^{2})=0$, but $$0=(T^{2}-\lambda^{2})=(T-\lambda)(T+\lambda)=(T-\lambda)(T-(-\lambda)).$$ Therefore $$ (T-\lambda)=0\ or\ (T-(-\lambda))=0,$$ so $\lambda$ or $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the operator T. $\blacksquare$

Comment: It's not true that $\bar{x} \ne 0$ implies $T^2 - \lambda^2 = 0$.  There are some nonzero vectors in the kernel of that operator, but not all are.

Comment: Fortunately, you don't need that.  $(T^2 - \lambda^2) \overline{x} = (T - \lambda) (T + \lambda) \overline{x} = 0$ implies that either $(T+\lambda) \overline{x} = 0$ or $y = (T+\lambda)\overline{x}$ is a nonzero vector with $(T-\lambda) y = 0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite.  By writing $(T^2-\lambda^2)=0$, you are making the claim that it is the $0$ operator.  This is not true.  Your factorization does work since $\lambda T(\bar{x})=T(\lambda\bar{x})$.  So, what you know is that
$$
(T^2-\lambda^2)(\bar{x})=(T-\lambda)(T+\lambda)(\bar{x}).
$$
You can still argue from there.

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem!